# Zend Gdata не подключается к Google Docs (Spreadsheets)

Tags: zend-framework, google-api

подключаюсь так:

```
    require_once('Zend/Gdata/Spreadsheets.php');
    require_once('Zend/Loader.php');

    $loader = new Zend_Loader();
    $loader->loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
    $loader->loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Query');
    $loader->loadClass('Zend_Gdata_AuthSub');
    $loader->loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
    $loader->loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets');
    $loader->loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_DocumentQuery');
    $loader->loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_CellQuery');

    $g_service = Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
    $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($login, $password, $g_service);
```

Дело в том, что буквально недели две назад все работало, а теперь выдает ошибку:
`Undefined offset: 1 in Zend\Gdata\ClientLogin.php(151)`

offset 1 нужен в разбиении строки по символу "=":

```
    foreach (explode("\n", $response->getBody()) as $l) {
        $l = chop($l);
        if ($l) {
            list($key, $val) = explode('=', $l, 2);// вот здесь
            $goog_resp[$key] = $val;
        }
    }
```

но `$response->getBody()` возвращает `https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps\n`, где нет никакого "="!

P.S. В аккаунте гугла разрешено поключение из любых мест и от любых приложений.

Comment: Разобрался) Гугл полностью перешел на oAuth 2.0, поэтому библиотека Zend GData устарела. Необходимо скачивать гугловскую библиотеку.

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1):

Гугл перешел на `oAuth 2.0`, в связи с чем изменился порядок подключения к аккаунту.

1. Создаем новый проект в https://console.developers.google.com
2. Заходим в него и слева выбираем `APIs & auth -> APIs` (для работы с `Google Docs` ничего добавлять не нужно, но если мы хотим иметь возможность создавать или удалять файлы - нужно подключить `Drive API`)
3. Выбираем `APIs & auth -> Credentials` и генерируем ключи нажатием на `Create New Client ID` (также нам понадобятся `Email address` и файл с расширением `P12` - генерятся там же)
4. **ВАЖНО!** Для записи в таблицу/документ необходимо в интерфейсе документа (Настройки доступа) вставить сгенерированный `email` в поле Пригласить людей
5. Скачиваем библиотеку Гугла https://developers.google.com/discovery/libraries
6. Импортируем в свой класс (у меня это `SpreadSheet`) следующие необходимые классы:

   ```
   require_once('Google/Loader.php');
   $loader = new Google_Loader();
   $loader->loadClass('Google_Config');
   $loader->loadClass('Google_Client');
   $loader->loadClass('Google_Auth_Abstract');
   $loader->loadClass('Google_Auth_OAuth2');
   $loader->loadClass('Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials');
   $loader->loadClass('Google_Cache_Abstract');
   $loader->loadClass('Google_Cache_File');
   $loader->loadClass('Google_Logger_Abstract');
   $loader->loadClass('Google_Logger_Null');
   $loader->loadClass('Google_Utils');
   $loader->loadClass('Google_Signer_Abstract');
   $loader->loadClass('Google_Signer_P12');
   $loader->loadClass('Google_Http_Request');
   $loader->loadClass('Google_IO_Abstract');
   $loader->loadClass('Google_IO_Curl');
   $loader->loadClass('Google_Http_CacheParser');
   $loader->loadClass('Google_Exception');
   $loader->loadClass('Google_Auth_Exception');
   ```
7. коннектимся:

   ```
   private function get_token()
   {
       // читаем скачанный файл *.P12
       $private_key = file_get_contents('gpk/crm0.p12');

       // используем сгенеренный email и scope - ссылку на API
       // (для таблиц это https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds)
       $credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
           $this->service_email, $this->get_url(), $private_key,
           'notasecret', 'http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer', false, false
       );
       $this->client = new Google_Client();
       $this->client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);

       if ($this->client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired())
           $this->client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();

       $tokenData = json_decode($this->client->getAccessToken());
       // access_token мы будем добавлять к каждому запросу вот так:
       // '...[url]...?access_token='.$this->token
       $this->token = $tokenData->access_token;
   }
   ```

Отправка запроса:

```
    private function send_request($url, $method='GET', $post_body=null, $save_request=false)
    {
        // добавляем версию API в заголовок
        $header = ['GData-Version' => '3.0'];
        // добавляем к запросу access_token, полученный ранее
        $url .= strpos($url, '?') === false ? '?' : '&';
        $url .= 'access_token='.$this->token;

        // для получения данных используется GET,
        // для обновления - PUT (в $post_body запихивать обновляемые данные в виде xml)
        // для вставки - POST (в $post_body запихивать вставляемые данные в виде xml)
        // для удаления - DELETE
        if ($method == 'POST' || $method == 'PUT')
            $header['Content-Type'] = 'application/atom+xml';

        $request = new Google_Http_Request($url, $method, $header, $post_body);
        $request = $this->client->getAuth()->authenticatedRequest($request);

        if ($request->getResponseHttpCode() == 200)
        {
            // собственно, полезная информация в виде xml
            $request = $request->getResponseBody();

            if ($save_request)
                $this->last_request = $request;

            // парсим xml в объект ObjectSimpleXML
            return simplexml_load_string($request);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

8. Вот здесь (англ.) подробно рассказывается какие запросы надо посылать [Google_API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/), [Google_API_for_spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/), [for_worksheets](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/worksheets)
9. Вот здесь можно вживую проверить, как Гугл реагирует на эти запросы:
   https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/